# What is the scope of a socket connection?

Tags: python, sockets

I have a question regarding scope of socket connection object in python.

If we set `socket.setdefaulttimeout(seconds)` globally in a class `A`, will it affect the third API calls and the network calls being performed by the instance of classes which are being initialized in class `A`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the default timeout will affect all new sockets created in the same process, so sayeth [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.setdefaulttimeout):

> Set the default timeout in seconds (float) for new socket objects. When the socket module is first imported, the default is None. See `settimeout()` for possible values and their respective meanings.

Your classes should likely set and manage their own sockets' timeouts (using the [per-socket `socket.socket.settimeout()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout)) if you don't want the default timeout to affect them.